# Stop praat from removing zeros

Tags: praat

I am relatively new to praat, and I have written a praat script that segments a larger file into smaller files based on a procedure:

`@instance: "sbc001", 756.00, 758.70
procedure instance: .sound$, .start, .end`

However, praat is removing final zeros. For example, if my start time is `756.00` and my end time is `758.70` it will name the file `sbc001_756_758_7` instead of naming it `sbc001_756_00_758_70`. Is there some way to force praat to include these zeros?

I might be able to modify my perl code to return 758 and 70 so that I could put them together as a decimal in praat, but I'm not sure how to do that while getting praat to read it as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not currently working with Praat, but I assume you’re calling something like string$() for the filename at some point. (Or, it’s being called implicitly to coerce your numerics into strings.) Can you use this function instead?

```
fixed$ (number, precision)
```

From [Praat Manual](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Formulas_5__String_functions.html): "formats a number as a string with precision digits after the decimal point. Thus, fixed$ (72.65687, 3) becomes the string 72.657, and fixed$ (72.65001, 3) becomes the string 72.650. In these examples, we see that the result can be rounded up and that trailing zeroes are kept. At least one digit of precision is always given, e.g. fixed$ (0.0000157, 3) becomes the string 0.00002. The number 0 always becomes the string 0."